# Mobile Application Development Environment Error

Tags: react-native, android-studio

PS E:\lab4\AwesomeProject> npx react-native doctor
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: N/A
- Version supported: 33.0.0
  ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

i wanted the app to run on my mobile, all sdk envoirement variables and paths are perfect still there is an error

Comment: Have you installed `Android SDK` inside android studio? This error is telling you that compiller could not find any SDK version so you should install it. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk?hl=pt-br)

Comment: yes i have, but still compiler was unable to find sdk

Comment: do you have `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` env variable configured?